# How to develop an intellisense-like word suggestion popup in MS Word using VSTO

Tags: ms-word, vsto, add-in, intellisense

I would like to develop a VSTO add-in to show a list of word suggestions when a user types the first few letters of certain words. The word-suggestion-list would work very similar to how intellisense works in Visual Studio, i.e., it pops up when I type the first few (or even one) letter, and to accept a suggestion, I can press tab/enter etc.

Can someone point to some sample code, or mention how I can popup such an intellisense-like suggestion list in MS Word using a VSTO add-in? What UI component should I use? Any pointers welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked on [SmartTags](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178786%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Sample code [here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/VSTO-Incorporating-Smart-2f8a6118)

Comment: This looks interesting - will check out. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The only reliable way that we found is the following scenario:
User starts typing a keyword, then press CTRL+SPACE and popup dialog appears with selected term in the list of terms. The dialog contains a search textbox, the already typed part of keyword is in the the textbox. The focus is in the textbox, so user just continue typing without any mouse moves. While she continue typing, the selected item in the list may changed. Selection is made by pressing ENTER.

You may see realization in http://rasvetera.com/terminauthor/en/